# How can I parse a XML file to a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I 'am trying to parse a XML file using the Python library `minidom` (even tried `xml.etree.ElementTree` API).

My XML (resource.xml)

```
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<quota_result xmlns="https://some_url">
    </quota_rule>
    <quota_rule name='max_mem_per_user/5'>
        <users>user1</users>
        <limit resource='mem' limit='1550' value='921'/>
    </quota_rule>
    <quota_rule name='max_mem_per_user/6'>
        <users>user2 /users>
        <limit resource='mem' limit='2150' value='3'/>
    </quota_rule>
</quota_result>
```

**I would like to parse this file and store inside a dictionnary the information in the following form and be able to access it:**

```
dict={user1=[resource,limit,value],user2=[resource,limit,value]}
```

So far I have only been able to do things like:

```
docXML = minidom.parse("resource.xml")
for node in docXML.getElementsByTagName('limit'): 
    print node.getAttribute('value')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` and `getAttribute` to trace the result:

```
dict_users = dict()
docXML = parse('mydata.xml')
users= docXML.getElementsByTagName("quota_rule")
for node in users:
    user = 'None'
    tag_user = node.getElementsByTagName("users") #check the length of the tag_user to see if tag <users> is exist or not
    if len(tag_user) ==0: 
        print "tag <users> is not exist"
    else:
        user = tag_user[0]
    resource = node.getElementsByTagName("limit")[0].getAttribute("resource")

    limit = node.getElementsByTagName("limit")[0].getAttribute("limit")

    value = node.getElementsByTagName("limit")[0].getAttribute("value")

    dict_users[user.firstChild.data]=[resource, limit, value]

    if user == 'None':
        dict_users['None']=[resource, limit, value]
    else:
        dict_users[user.firstChild.data]=[resource, limit, value]

print(dict_users) # remove the <users>user1</users> in xml
```

Output:

```
 tag <users> is not exist
{'None': [u'mem', u'1550', u'921'], u'user2': [u'mem', u'2150', u'3']}
```

Comment: do you know how to check whether the tag **<users>** exists or not ?

Comment: You can simply check the length of the node element is 0 or not, 0--> not exist, refer to the updated answer.

Comment: hi,i have two questions  : 
1 any idea how i access the name tag  using getElementsByTagName ?
2 why do we use element [0] in  node.getElementsByTagName("limit")[0] ?